# Are there any design patterns used in the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I would like to know: are any [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) design patterns are used in the [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)?

**BOUNTY:**

I have seen the MSDN link below in an answer. Are there any post/video or can you can list patterns and most importantly WHERE it is used?

Comment: This can serve as a list of design patterns used in .net. I am okay making this as a wiki if it serves the interest of this question

Comment: Probably all of the GoF patterns

Comment: Related post - [What design patterns are used throughout the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3252499/465053)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an article that discusses this very topic:

[Discover the Design Patterns You're Already Using in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/july/discovering-the-design-patterns-you-re-already-using-in-net)

And now the MVC pattern can be added with ASP.NET MVC. :)

EDIT:  Since your edit / request for more info:

Here's an article that lists several patterns and where they are used in the framework.
[Structural Design Patterns and .NET Framework 2.0](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2006_11/article1.pdf)

The Providers in .NET are all the Provider model pattern:
[ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Model: Introduction to the Provider Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa479030(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

The provider patterns in .NET also use the Strategy Pattern.

The factory pattern is used in several places and here's a sample where it's used in ASP.NET.
[Exploring the Factory Design Pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20110415090421/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817667(pandp.10).aspx)

Here's a webcast on [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29)'s in .NET:
[MSDN Webcast: Design Patterns in .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20100118174147/http://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032293567&CountryCode=US)

I haven't watched it so I am not sure how much it goes into how they are used in the Framework...

As already mentioned in a comment, the GoF patterns are likely all in use in the .NET framework.  Where is not exactly the easiest to answer as the framework is massive and unless MS publishes as such listed in some of the examples given it is not always obvious.  The more familiar one is with a pattern the more likely you would notice a framework class that was employing it.

Hopefully the extra links I have added help you.

Additionally, dofactory has a [for sale kit ($79-99)](https://www.dofactory.com/products) that is about teaching how to use/implement GoF patterns in .NET BUT they do list on the reading they will also explain where MS uses them in the Framework.

Comment: I hate lists like that. The vast majority of GoF Design Patterns are not appropriate for .NET programmers. There are far better patterns that solve the same goals, but do so using the features offered by the .NET platform. Unfortunately they don't have fancy names so they tend to be ignored in literature.

Comment: Just giving him what he asked for. :)

Comment: @Grauenwolf and @Paco: Paco thinks that probably all of them are but Grauenwolf contends that most are probably not appropriate. i have a feeling that Grauenwolf is closer to being correct but i would LOVE to hear a discussion on Grauenwolf's position or a link to such a discussion. Or can you name a pattern or two that are not appropriate and why?

Comment: As examples, the traditional 'observer' and 'strategy' patterns which are typically implemented with interfaces and classes in other languages are better implemented in .Net/C# with delegates

Comment: The "Visitor" pattern is one I particularly dislike. The design assumes that you can modify interfaces after the fact as new classes are created. But of course we all know that interfaces in .NET should never be changed after they are published.

Comment: MSDN links are now dead.

Comment: Ha, not too surprising seeing how this question & answer is nearly 8 years old.... :-)  Looking at those links that are for msdn mags, the website only keeps online through 2009.  These links were likely from older than 2009.

Answer (score 45):

The .NET framework uses **many** of the Gang of Four patterns. Here are just a few examples:

**Creational patterns**

- **Abstract Factory**: `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory`. Every member function of this class is a factory method.
- **Builder**: The WCF channel construction infrastructure.
- **Factory Method**:

  - `System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction()`. The type of transaction created depends on the underlying IDbConnection implementation.
  - `WebRequest.Create()` returns a concrete type that depends on the URL scheme.
- **Prototype** - used in framework for cloning and serialization
- **Singleton** - used as an activation method in WCF, i.e. a web service may be treated as a singleton by the WCF infrastructure. Ditto for .NET Remoting.

**Structural patterns**

- **Adapter**: The ADO.NET providers, eg `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection` etc. Each provider is an adapter for its specific database.
- **Composite**: many examples

  - `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and its derived classes.
  - `System.Web.UI.Control` and its derived classes.
  - `System.Xml.XmlNode` and its derived classes.
- **Decorator**:

  - `System.Windows.Controls.Decorator` (in WPF).
  - Some implementations of `Stream` are decorators around an inner stream (e.g. `GZipStream`, `CryptoStream`).
- **Facade**: `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`. XmlSerializer hides a complex task (that includes generating assemblies on the fly!) behind a very easy-to-use class.
- **Proxy**: The web service proxies generated by svcutil.exe and deriving from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>`

**Behavioral Patterns**

- **Chain of responsibility**: `System.Web.UI.Control.OnBubbleEvent()` and `System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent()`.
- **Command**:`System.Windows.Input.ICommand` (in WPF).
- **Interpreter**: `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` and related classes.
- **Iterator**: many examples

  - `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.
  - `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`.
  - `System.Data.IDataReader`.
- **Memento**: The .NET *Serializable* pattern is a variation on the *Memento* pattern.
- **Observer** - The .NET event mechanism.
- **Strategy** - Sort method in ArrayList
- **Template Method** - Render method for custom controls
- **Visitor**  : `System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor` ([used internally by [LINQ]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query))

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for.. Thanks  But is the specific example for Iterator pattern IEnumerator that has MoveNext() Method ?

Comment: @Ananth -- I would say yes. IEnumerator is the iterator pattern, and IEnumerable is the most common way to consume it.

Answer (score 6):

Read the "Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries". This book will show you the real design patterns that .NET was based on.

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting that one... :)

Comment: Second that! It's Chapter 9 ("Common Design Patterns") in the first edition - I keep that copy at home and the second edition at work. :)

Comment: +1: I've got the second edition of this book. It really gives great insight how to design a framework and indeed some examples are given how parts of the .Net framework are designed.

Comment: doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely. For instance, *Factory pattern* is used in ADO.NET data provider classes. *Singleton pattern* is used in .NET remoting. *Dispose pattern* is used in resource management.

Answer (score 0):

The BeginXXX and EndXXX methods in the BCL are based loosely on the *Asynchronous Completion Token* pattern.

Answer (score 0):

- System.Net.WebClient is an example for the Façade Pattern.
- System.IO.Stream: Classic Async Pattern
- System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker: Event-Based Async pattern
- As already mentioned: Dispose pattern is used nearly everywhere in the framework
- System.Control: Template Method Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many design patterns used in .Net framework BCL.  In fact this is the best Place to look at to learn the design pattern's usage in real term perspective.

## Pattern          :     Implementation

Observer Pattern :  Implemented as Events & Delegates

Decorator Pattern:  Implemented in System.IO Stream classes

Iterator Pattern : IEnumerable & Iterator

Strategy Pattern : Implemented in Linq thru Lambda experssion queries (list.Where(expression))

Factory Pattern : In System.Net.WebRequest

Adapter Pattern :  TLB Import / RCW (Runtime Calleable wrappers)

Please check out this video for detailed presentation on this topic.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riHGGYHVoaQ&list=PL2_Cl8E2bG36PGuBGesHFPVM1s6M02JmN