# C# GOF Pattern Examples

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Are there any C# GOF design pattern examples? I Keep finding [this site](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) which does have examples, but the "C# Optimised" examples are only available when you purchase one of their products.

Comment: This question might be of assistance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252499/what-design-patterns-are-implemented-in-the-net-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book called "Design Patterns in C#" by Steven John Metsker that gives examples in C# for the 23 classic GoF patterns.

Edit: On the "freely available online" side, there is a decent series on Code Project by [this author](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=52003).

Comment: +1. This is a good book. It was written in .Net 1.x days, at least the edition I have, so there might be a few patterns that are longer optimal (syntactically, or otherwise), but it still worth a good read.

Comment: @Nathan Yeah, that's true. The edition I have is from 2004 and there is probably better syntax for a lot of the examples. The best use for it is probably for use in understanding the patterns by someone who is already proficient in C# rather than the other way around.

Comment: Also a book Design Patterns in .NET (https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484243657) (authored by yours truly)

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend [Head-First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124).

It is technically Java, but I've never looked at Java before and was completely readable for a C# developer. I checked it out from the library, only to find out that many of the .NET developers I know own it themselves already.