# Is the Chain of Responsibility used in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to learn more about the Chain of Responsibility design pattern.  Every single example I see online gives the simplest example i.e. a Logger that writes a different message to the Console depending on what handler handles the request.

Are there any real life examples in the .NET framework? I have looked at the following links:

1. [What design patterns are used throughout the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252499/what-design-patterns-are-used-throughout-the-net-framework)
2. http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern
3. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Comment: Here is a simple good example (Check Real-world code in C#)  : http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern

Comment: @Abdullah Dibas, I posted that link in my question.  Did you read it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that.

Comment: A classic example COR is processing [HelpRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events in WindowsForms. See [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=helprequested).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ASP.NET Core uses this design principle for web request handling. Each web request goes through the chain of handlers (called [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x)), and each handler might do something with request and decide if request should go to the next handler in a chain or not. Per documentation:

> Middleware is software that's assembled into an application pipeline
>   to handle requests and responses. Each component:
>
> - Chooses whether to pass the request to the next component in the
>     pipeline.
> - Can perform work before and after the next component in the
>     pipeline is invoked.

Which is, I think, as close to responsibility chain as it can get.

Also, even regular .NET event often works as implementation of this principle. 
Invoking .NET event goes through the list of subscribers (event handlers) and invokes them one after another. Many events (for example, UI events in WPF, such as mouse click) have `Handled` boolean flag in their event arguments. Event handler might set this flag to `true` to notify subsequent handlers in a chain to ignore this event (because it has already been "handled"), or leave it `false`, notifying next handler in a chain that it might still do something with it. This is also implementation of chain of responsibility.

Comment: @Lepijohnny well I'm not a pattern guy. Most patterns are quite controversial, so I don't like to argue about specific details. One might say that it more fits "Pipeline" pattern or something else, I won't argue with that.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic yes that is the same, I will delete the comment to avoid confusion... :)

Answer (score 3):

Taken directly from book [.Net Design patterns](https://www.amazon.in/NET-Design-Patterns-Praseed-Pai-ebook/dp/B01GEJKJ8S?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=016d1f47-a9e8-4e43-9e6a-bd9737b4ad25) where it explained how chain of responsibility used in asp.net request execution pipeline:

**Chain of responsibility pattern in ASP.net :**

> The chain of responsibility pattern is a design pattern consisting of
>   a series of processing objects through which we pass a data stream for
>   filtration or modification. Ultimately, the process terminates when
>   the data stream passes the last processing object at the end of the
>   chain. The ASP.NET pipeline is a wonderful example where the chain of
>   responsibility pattern is leveraged to provide an extensible
>   programming model. The ASP.NET infrastructure implements WebForms API,
>   ASMX Web services, WCF, ASP.NET Web API, and ASP.NET MVC using HTTP
>   modules and handlers. Every request in the pipeline passes through a
>   series of modules (a class that implements IHttpModule) before it
>   reaches its target handler (a class that implements IHttpHandler).
>   Once a module in the pipeline has done its duty, it passes the
>   responsibility of the request processing to the next module in the
>   chain. Finally, it reaches the handler. The following code snippet
>   shows how one can write an object that leverages the chain of
>   responsibility pattern to create a module that filters an incoming
>   request. These filters are configured as chains and will pass the
>   request content to the next filter in the chain by the ASP.net
>   runtime:

```
public class SimpleHttpModule : IHttpModule 
{ 
  public SimpleHttpModule(){} 
  public String ModuleName 
  { 
    get { return "SimpleHttpModule"; } 
  } 
  public void Init(HttpApplication application) 
  { 
    application.BeginRequest +=  
    (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest)); 
    application.EndRequest +=  
    (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest)); 
  } 
  private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source,  
  EventArgs e) 
  { 
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source; 
    HttpContext context = application.Context; 
    context.Response.Write(SomeHtmlString); 
  } 
  private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) 
  { 
    HttpApplication application =      (HttpApplication)source; 
    HttpContext context = application.Context; 
    context.Response.Write(SomeHtmlString); 
  } 
  public void Dispose(){} 
} 

<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <httpModules> 
      <add name=" SimpleHttpModule " type=" SimpleHttpModule "/> 
    </httpModules> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

> In the ASP.NET pipeline, a request passes through a series of HTTP
>   modules before it hits a handler. A simple HTTP handler routine is
>   given as follows:

```
public class SimpleHttpHandler: IHttpHandler 
{ 
  public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context){ 
    context.Response.Write("The page request ->" +          
    context.Request.RawUrl.ToString()); 
  } 
  public bool IsReusable 
  { 
    get{ return true; } 
  } 
}
```

> We can configure the handler as given next. Whenever we create an
>   ASP.NET resource with the .smp extension, the handler will be
>   SimpleHttpHandler:

```
<system.web> 
      <httpHandlers> 
        <add verb="*" path="*.smp" type="SimpleHttpHandler"/> 
      </httpHandlers> 
    </system.web>
```

> The preceding technique of leveraging the chain of responsibility
>   pattern is available in other web technologies such as Java Servlets
>   (called Servlet filters) and also available in IIS as ISAPI filters.